# How to use default style in winUI package

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, winui

There is a ResourceDictionary :

```xml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <Style TargetType="Button">

        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="RoyalBlue" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want to use it as defualt Button control.

The App.Xaml includes the dictionarydictionary :

```xml
<Application x:Class="EroMangaManager.UWP.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">
    <Application.Resources>
        <muxc:XamlControlsResources>
            <muxc:XamlControlsResources.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionarys/DefaultControlStyle.xaml" />
            </muxc:XamlControlsResources.MergedDictionaries>
        </muxc:XamlControlsResources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The old UI is original UWP UI(not WinUI package),and the default button control can correctly work.

But if I change the UI to WinUI 2.8.2 package, the default button control can't work.

I tried to define the style in App.xaml rather than in outside xaml file :

```xml
<Application x:Class="EroMangaManager.UWP.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:muxc="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="RoyalBlue" />
        </Style>
        <muxc:XamlControlsResources x:Key="de">
            <muxc:XamlControlsResources.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ResourceDictionarys/DefaultControlStyle.xaml" />
            </muxc:XamlControlsResources.MergedDictionaries>
        </muxc:XamlControlsResources>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Compiling is Ok,however when running to the Page.Construct function,the code `this.InitializeComponent();`  will throw exception.

How can it correctly use default with WinUI package?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and it's an unexpected behavior. Currently you can try the following two solutions.

1.Use the new ResourceKey in the ResourceDictionary(DefaultControlStyle.xaml).

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NewButtonBackgroundBrush" Color="HotPink" />

<!-- Resources for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button -->
<!-- I copy this form generic.xaml  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.22621.0\Generic\generic.xaml" -->
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackground" ResourceKey="NewButtonBackgroundBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundBaseMediumLowBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBackgroundDisabled" ResourceKey="SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonForeground" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonForegroundPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonForegroundDisabled" ResourceKey="SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" ResourceKey="SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightBaseMediumLowBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushPressed" ResourceKey="SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="ButtonBorderBrushDisabled" ResourceKey="SystemControlDisabledTransparentBrush" />
<StaticResource x:Key="NewButtonBorderThicknessValue" ResourceKey="NewButtonBorderThickness" />


<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="NewBtnStyle">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackground}"/>
</Style>
```

2.Define the style of the button in the resource of each page.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///DefaultControlStyle.xaml"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you ,sir ! maybe use x:key is better

Comment: Do styles in `DefaultControlStyle.xaml` work after using x:key?

Comment: yes,but repea using {StaticResource style} is too boring

Comment: @大江东去fff In the uwp app, if you add a x:key for the `muxc:XamlControlsResources`, the button style could work, but other styles you defined in the resource file will not work.  So we suggest you using other ways.

Comment: @大江东去fff Haven't heard from you for a while. Any updates about this? Have you checked my relay about Button default style in winUI package?